# Найти повторяющиеся данные с выделением нужных

Tags: sql, oracle

Задача найти не корректно заведенные записи в БД ORACLE
Пример:

```
  ID   |  VENDOR |  NUMB  | STATUS |
  _________________________________
   1   | ERIC    | 22     |  DIS   |
   1   | HUA     | 22     |  PLAN  |
   1   | NNN     | 22     |  PLAN  |
   2   | ERIC    | 56     |  DIS   |
   2   | HUA     | 56     |  PLAN  |
```

Нужно вывести в отчет записи 'NNN', но при этом с таким же ID должны содержаться записи  'ERIC"  и 'HUA'.
Может к таблице STATUS тоже можно привязаться.

```
SELECT ID  
  FROM tbl
 WHERE STATUS  = 'Planned'
 GROUP ID  
HAVING COUNT(ID) >= 2
```

Видимо не поможет.

Comment: вполне может помочь. если взять только требуемые VENDOR (если в таблице бывают и другие) и считать уникальных вендоров на id, т.е. `count(distinct VENDOR)`

Answer (score 1):

> вывести в отчет записи 'NNN', но при этом с таким же ID должны содержаться записи 'ERIC" и 'HUA'.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` t1
WHERE t1.vendor = 'NNN'
  AND 2 = (SELECT COUNT( /* DISTINCT */ vendor)
           FROM `table` t2
           WHERE t1.id = t2.id
             AND t2.vendor IN ('ERIC','HUA'))
```

Comment: БД большая, запрос наверное будет долго выполнятся...

Comment: @AndreyIvanov Это уже другой вопрос ;)

Comment: А почему `distinct` закомментирован? Он явно нужен.

Comment: *почему distinct закомментирован?* Мне лично неизвестно, является ли пара (id, vendor) уникальной. А DDL таблицы кто-то неприлично зажал...

Comment: Являются уникальными пара ID - VENDOR - STATUS

Comment: @AndreyIvanov Это, я извиняюсь, тройка.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.id
      ,t.vendor
      ,t.numb
      ,t.status
from   (select t.id
              ,t.vendor
              ,t.numb
              ,t.status
              ,count(distinct t.vendor) over(partition by t.id) as cnt
        from   tbl t
        where  t.vendor in ('ERIC', 'HUA', 'NNN')) t
where  t.cnt = 3
and    t.vendor = 'NNN'
```

Comment: Без подзапросов. В зависимости от ситуации может работать на несколько порядков быстрее, чем с подзапросами.

Comment: @Victorov, мне чегото кажется что условие "но при этом с таким же ID должны содержаться записи 'ERIC" и 'HUA'." не выполняется

Comment: @Yaroslav а пример покажите, на котором это условие не выполняется. По моему все Ок

Comment: and   t.vendor = 'NNN' убрать и будет ок, а так одна строка выводится

Comment: @Pithein так вывести то нужно только запись с `vendor='NNN'`. Просто надо проверить, что у нее также есть записи с `vendor in ('ERIC', 'HUA')`

Comment: @Victorov, там же говорится что в отчете должны содержатся записи NNN, но при этом еще должны содержатся записи с ERIC, HUA если их ID равен ID записи NNN

Comment: @Yaroslav постановку ТС я понял так "Нужно вывести в отчет записи 'NNN', для которых в БД существуют записи 'ERIC" и 'HUA'". То есть, нужно выводить только строку с NNN.

Comment: @Victorov, 50 на 50

Comment: @Yaroslav правильного ответа мы наверное не узнаем уже никогда. Не похоже, чтобы автор собирался возвращаться к этому вопросу)

Comment: @Victorov, ага, оставим как есть)

Answer (score 1):

Через внешнее соединение можно решить Вашу задачу

```
with s
  as (select 1      as "ID"
           , 'ERIC' as "VENDOR"
           , 22     as "NUMB"
           , 'DIS'  as "STATUS"
      from dual
      union all
      select 1      as "ID"
           , 'HUA'  as "VENDOR"
           , 22     as "NUMB"
           , 'PLAN' as "STATUS"
      from dual
      union all
      select 1      as "ID"
           , 'NNN'  as "VENDOR"
           , 22     as "NUMB"
           , 'PLAN' as "STATUS"
      from dual
            union all
      select 2      as "ID"
           , 'ERIC'  as "VENDOR"
           , 56     as "NUMB"
           , 'PLAN' as "STATUS"
      from dual
      union all
      select 2      as "ID"
           , 'HUA'  as "VENDOR"
           , 56     as "NUMB"
           , 'PLAN' as "STATUS"
      from dual
      )
 select s2.*
from s s1
left outer
join s s2 on s2.id = s1.id
where s1.vendor = 'NNN'
```

---

```
    ID VEND       NUMB STAT

     1 ERIC         22 DIS 
     1 HUA          22 PLAN
     1 NNN          22 PLAN
```

Answer (score 1):

> вывести в отчет записи 'NNN', но при этом с таким же ID должны содержаться записи 'ERIC" и 'HUA'

```
SELECT res.ID, res.VENDOR, res.NUMB, res.STATUS
  FROM (
       SELECT Result.ID, Result.VENDOR, Result.NUMB, Result.STATUS,
              MIN(Result.VENDOR) OVER (PARTITION BY Result.VENDOR) as min_cust,
              MAX(Result.VENDOR) OVER (PARTITION BY Result.VENDOR) as max_cust
         FROM TBL Result
        WHERE Result.VENDOR IN ('NNN', 'ERIC', 'HUA') AND Result.ID IN (1)
       ) res
 WHERE min_cust=max_cust;
```